# Would it be strange to replace "crowded" with "massed"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I couldn't find this usage on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=oI6KW779N8qa8wXJiIHYBA&q=%22%20train%20was%20massed%22&oq=%22%20train%20was%20massed%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1362.1362.0.1531.1.1.0.0.0.0.47.47.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.teRljlSbaZ0) (search results), so I'm not very sure if it's a right way to use the word "mass".

Example sentence:

> The train was more massed than usual.

Comment: What do you mean by "on Google"? Are you saying you searched online dictionaries? Or Google Books? Or just websites in general?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Search results.

Comment: That's not a good answer.  What were you searching?  Better to confine such searches to Google Books. At least then you can be reasonably confident that the search is going against texts written for the most part by native speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying question is whether there is a transitive verb, **to mass something**. There is, and it means "to arrange something" or "to group something" or to "gather something together".

> They massed a considerable quantity of arms [weapons] in the jail-house.

A considerable quantity of weapons was massed in the jail-house.  The jail-house itself was not "massed".

In the same way, it is not your train that would be massed. The passengers are massed. But you could say:

> The train cars had been massed in the train yard.

The cars had been  brought to the yard.

There is also an intransitive verb, **to mass**, which means "to gather together in a crowd or in a (somewhat disorderly) group".

> The children massed near the ice-cream truck.

Answer (score 3):

Using 'massed' in place of 'crowded' as in your example sentence is not a correct usage. You could use 'packed' though.

Answer (score 2):

No, **mass** as a verb means to gather or mobilize people, usually troops, or for people to assemble.

> They are going to attack us! They have been massing troops in the past month.
>
> A crowd of over a hundred have massed outside your house.

You have a number of other options for synonyms of "crowded".

> The train was more **packed/crammed/cramped/congested** than usual.